# Rails Bundle Install failing on bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler, osx-mavericks, gemset

I just did a fresh install of mavricks, Postgres.app, RVM, Git.

I created a standard new rails app and everything worked fine.

However when I tried to grab a project from github and can not get bundle install to run.

```
  d3 git:(master) bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Updating git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git
fatal: Could not parse object '9c6c07f74ff515cf38380b014cfede14a4f0eae4'.
Git error: command `git reset --hard 9c6c07f74ff515cf38380b014cfede14a4f0eae4`
in directory
/Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@d3/bundler/gems/bootstrap-sass-9c6c07f74ff5
has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
'/Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@d3/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e'
```

I tried to remove the project and clone it again.

I tried removing the gemset and removing all the gems from the gemset.

I also tried to follow the error message and remove the cache folder.

Please help I really need to get back to working on this project.

```
Update:
```

I just tried a bundle update as well.

```
➜  d3 git:(master) bundle update
Updating git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git
fatal: ambiguous argument '3': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
Git error: command `git rev-parse 3` in directory
/Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@d3/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e
has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
'/Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@d3/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e'
```

Update

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.15'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'mixpanel-ruby'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', :git => 'git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git', :branch => '3'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'haml_coffee_assets'
gem 'execjs'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'jasmine-rails'
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'spin'
end

gem 'active_link_to'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem "aws-sdk"
gem 'backbone-on-rails'
gem 'browser'
gem 'devise'
gem 'gon'
gem 'js-routes'
gem 'oj'
gem 'pusher'
gem 'rabl'
gem 'simple_form'
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the content of the Gemfile?

Comment: @mohamagdy here is my Gemfile, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no branch `3` in https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/ anymore. That's why Git is complaining. So you need to change it from:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', :github => 'git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git', :branch => '3'
```

to:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', :git => 'git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git'
```

or use a shorthand syntax:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', :github => 'thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass'
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It is installing gems